# Inheritance - Abstract vs. Virtual

Tags: c#

Let's say I have an `Animal` class and a `Cat` class that inherits from `Animal`. `Animal` class has a virtual `Sleep` method and the `Cat` class overrides that `Sleep` method.

```
class Animal
{
    .....

    public virtual void Sleep()
    {
    .....
    }
}

class Cat: Animal
{
    .....

    public override void Sleep()
    {
    .....
    }
}
```

If I have a `List<Animal> animals` variable and add objects of both type `Animal` and type `Cat`, when I iterate the list and run the `Sleep` method, `Cat` objects will have their own `Sleep` method run. So far so good.

But in terms of code readability and maintainability, should I rather have an abstract `Sleep` method somewhere else and have that overridden in both `Animal` and `Cat` classes? Because otherwise, for instance when you click "Go To Definition" in VS, it takes you to the `Sleep` method of the `Animal` class, which might create a confusion for another developer reading the code.

What is the best practice regarding this?

Comment: Note that since VS 2015, it also has a "go to implementation" too, that can go directly to either the base virtual method or to the overriden one.

Answer (score 4):

The choice between abstract and virtual has imo very little to do with *readability*.

It is rather a design-choice based on functionality.  If your base class can provide standard behaviour for a certain method, but children can have their own specific behaviour, make the method virtual.   If there's no default behaviour, make the method abstract.

Answer (score 1):

Abstract equals must be implemented when inheriting.
Virtual equals you may or may not implement this when inheriting.

You should not worry about other developers go to implementation functionality. 
You should worry about what do you want to achive in your design.

Document your base/abstract class well and others will be able to follow your code.

Give meaning full names like.. SleepWhenButtonClicked... And not Sleep

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you.

Do you want your consumers to create an `Animal` that isn't a derived type?

- If so, make `Animal` `abstract`.
- If not, a `virtual` method is one way to go.

Comment: He's asking about an abstract method. Your answer relates to whether to use an abstract class, which is a separate question.